# Import JS file placed in /public into JS file in /src

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vuejs2

I am currently working on implementing OAuth authentication into my Vue app.

The authentication logic consists out of two files, the `src/auth.js` and `public/silent-renewal.html`. The first file contains all the logic to interact with the OAuth server. The second file is used to process the callback when the access token is renewed in the background.

In addition to these two files there is the file `public/oidc-settings.js`. This file contains a JSON variable defining the settings for the OAuth server.
It defines a JSON variable with the settings and a method to access them:

```
const settings = {
  authority: 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/auth-example',
  client_id: 'webclient-service',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/callback',
  response_type: 'code',
  response_mode: 'query',
  scope: 'openid profile',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/logout',
  silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/silent-renewal.html',
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true
}

function getSettings () {
  return settings
}
```

In the `silent-renewal.html` file I access the settings by importing them with a `script` tag (`<script src='oidc-settings.js'></script`.

The problem is that I don't know how to access the `oidc-settings.js` from my `auth.js`. Currently I define the exact same settings again in the `auth.js` file.

How can I import a Javascript file placed in the `public` folder of my application into a Javascript file in the `src` folder?

Comment: was the project created with vue-cli? it should be just 
import "whatever" from '../public/../../'

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how you can navigate into a different folder, you can navigate up one level of a folder using `../`.

It would look like this: `'../public/your-file.js'`

If you need to navigate up two (or more), just add another `../` for each level like this `'../../folder/file.js'`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import something that is not set to be imported, probably your path is correct but you need to make the function that returns the configuration accessible to be imported.

Just change your settings file , so your function getSetting can be imported

```
export const getSettings = () => {
  return settings
}
```

then in your "src" file just

```
 import { getSettings } from '../public/../../'
```

Comment: I tried this. But when I add `export` to `getSettings` the `silent-renewal.html` (where I also use the `oidc-settings.js`) throws an error when I open it: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`.

Comment: @rule I've not seen this specific variation before `'../public/../../'`. How would this work? Does it go up one folder into public and then up another two folders? Little confused here.